# 内包表記をベタに開いて書く

Tags: python, opencv

[Python, OpenCVで画像にモザイク処理（全面、一部、顔など）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-mosaic/) のページに
以下のような記述があります。

> ```
> imgs = [Image.fromarray(mosaic(src, 1 / i)) for i in range(1, 25)]
> ```

これをベタで書くとき、上記の左辺 `imgs =` の部分はどう書くのでしょうか？

たぶん、こんな感じになるのではないかと思うのですが、

```
for i in range(1, 25):
 Image.fromarray(mosaic(src, 1 / i))
```

ここから先がよくわからないです。

```
for i in range(1, 25):
 imgs += Image.fromarray(mosaic(src, 1 / i))
```

ではないみたいです。

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'imgs' referenced before assignment
```

というエラーが出ます。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考: [for loopでの変数定義](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じサイト作者の記事がこちらにあります。
[Pythonリスト内包表記の使い方](https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-comprehension/)

> 等価なfor文とともに例を示す。
>
> ```
> squares = [i**2 for i in range(5)]
> print(squares)
> # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> squares = []
> for i in range(5):
>     squares.append(i**2)
>
> print(squares)
> # [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
> ```

その内容を応用すれば以下のようになるでしょう。

```
imgs = []
for i in range(1, 25):
    imgs.append(Image.fromarray(mosaic(src, 1 / i)))
```

他に参考になる記事
[pythonの内包表記を少し詳しく](https://qiita.com/y__sama/items/a2c458de97c4aa5a98e7)

Comment: ありがとうございました。ご教示いただいた内容で、無事、解決しました。